# Alamofire + bonjour , no network connection

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm developing a service browser for iOS device and i'm facing some problems.
I've correctly discovered services by using NSNetServiceBrowser and resolved it but if i try to do a .GET request using Alamofire to the hostname of the NSNetService returned by discovery i get a cannot resolve name 
i've used this code to do the request

```
var url : String = "http://\(self.servers[0].hostName):32400/library/sections"
Alamofire.request(.GET, url.lowercaseString,encoding: ParameterEncoding.URL).responsePropertyList { request, response, result in
    if let array = response.result.value as? [[String: String]] {
        print("bau")
    }
}
```

self.servers[0].hostName returns a string like iMac-di-Tiz.local.
and opening the url in Chrome i get the page correctly.
Does anyone have tried it and made it work?

Comment: Just a side note, swift comes with a native networking framework, you should have a look

Comment: i used Alamofire just because i already know it but i think that for a simple .GET request i can learn swift native networking